# Unable to load empty string values for vertex and edge properties using Neptune Loader

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am unable to load empty string values for vertex and edge properties, as far as I know I am following Gremlin Load Format and providing the right request JSON to Neptune loader endpoint.

This is how the vertex csv file(generated using pandas) on s3 looks

[image]

The request payload sent to loader endpoint(http://database:8182/loader)

```
{
   "source": "s3://bucket/dir/or/object/containing/csvfile/",
   "format" : "csv",
   "iamRoleArn" : "arn:sample",
   "region" : "us-east-1",
   "failOnError" : "FALSE",
   "parserConfiguration" : {
       "allowEmptyStrings": true
     }
}
```

The data is loaded successfully.

1. Vertex is created.
2. *'label*' and 'id' fields are assigned with values mentioned in the csv.
3. *'key2'* property shows its value as 'value'(mentioned in csv).
4. ***'key1'* property is not found/loaded in database in spite of providing allowEmptyStrings as true in
   request payload.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want an empty string, you need to encapsulate it in quotes within the CSV:

```
~id,~label,key1:String,key2:String
testid1,testlabel,"",value2
testid2,testlabel,value1,""
```

If the field is not encapsulated in quotes, it is treated as null (which is different than an empty string).  Null values are implicit within TinkerPop as it presently stands.